# ForkJoin for multiple observables

Tags: angular

I am using Observable.forkJoin to send 2 service requests in angular 4.
I am getting the responses correctly.But I would like to handle the scenario in which one response is a success and the other is a failure.How can I achieve this.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `catch` for each request to handle failures and check results for Error after:

```
var source1 = Rx.Observable.return(42);
  .catch(err => Rx.Observable.return(new Error('request failed'));
var source2 = Rx.Observable.throw('err')
  .catch(err => Rx.Observable.return(new Error('request failed'));

var source = source1.forkJoin(source2, (s1, s2) => {
    return {
      s1,
      s2
    }; 
});
```